# R: Merge data frames based on substring match

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, merge, substring

I have two data frames that I would like to merge by protein accession names.

df1 is a data frame containing protein accession names correlated to a gene (and there are several of these names). df1 thus contain a "list" of these names separated by semicolons in string format with unique values that never occur again in df1. I have written these names as "A1, B1, ..." below:

```
df1:

Name                a.value
A1;B1;C1            ...
A2                  ...
A3;B3               ...
A4;B4;C4;D4;E4;F4   ...
```

---

df2 is a data frame containing only one of these accession named per row:

```
df2:

Name  b.value
A2    ...
B3    ...
B4    ...
```

Both df1 and df2 contain other columns.

I would like the merged data frame be merged so that rows are matched if the accession name in df2 exists as one of the names df1 as follows:

```
A2   A2                 a.value  b.value
B3   A3;B3              ...      ...
B4   A4;B4;C4;D4;E4;F4  ...      ...
```

And of course, other columns from both data frames are included.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, and let me know if you need me to elaborate on something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the requested output:

```
l <- strsplit(as.character(df1$Name), ';')
df1new <- data.frame(Name = unlist(l), Name.string = rep(df1$Name, lengths(l)))
merge(df2, df1new, by = 'Name', all.x = TRUE)
```

The result:

```
   Name       Name.string
1:   A2                A2
2:   B3             A3;B3
3:   B4 A4;B4;C4;D4;E4;F4
```